# jQuery get ID of element within element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, svg

Sorry all, my question was not explicit enough. Some of the `g` elements in the div are groups of `svg` elements. have  a look [at a fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/TheRealPapa/rLJMh/495/). So, the grouping allows for `title` and for CSS across multiple objects. When someone clicks on any SVG object, I want top get the id of the parent `g`.

---

My html contains a div (`id="svg-container"`) with a large number of SVG elements each with its own ID.

I have an event listener set up on page load which listens for a click event on the container div (`svg-container`) and I want to pull up the id of the SVG object (if one was clicked).

HTML:

```
<div id="svg-container">
   <g id="svg1">...</g>
   <g id="svg2">...</g>
   <g id="svg3">...</g>
....
</div>
```

Comment: Add event listeners to all the `g` tags/elements within `svg-container`? You could use `document.getElementById('svg-container').getElementsByTagName('g');` and a for loop to attach the events to each one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attach handler to the `g` elements:

```
$('#svg-container').on('click', 'g', function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  console.log(this.id);
});
```

```js
$('#svg-container').on('click', 'g', function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  console.log(this.id);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="svg-container">
  <svg id="world-map" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="998 -261 1610.2 1055.2" xml:space="preserve" enable-background="new 998 -261 1610.2 1055.2">
    <g class="oceania new-zealand" id="new-zealand">
      <title>New Zealand</title>
      <path d="M2559.9,582.6L2551.4 553.9 2547.7 553.4 2549.4 573.6 2547.2 582.7 2538.2 589.4 2538.7 597.2 2538.7 605.7 2541.2 608.7 2565.9 587.4 2565.9 582.6 z"></path>
      <path d="M2505.9,618.4L2480.7 629.4 2481.9 634.2 2495.7 640.9 2510.9 626.9 2519.9 625.7 2521.2 619.1 2534.4 606.2 2529.7 597.2 z"></path>
    </g>
    <g class="oceania indonesia" id="indonesia">
      <title>Indonesia</title>
      <path d="M2276.6,324.4L2268.9 319.5 2267.6 311.8 2223.9 273.9 2223.4 277.9 2234.9 297.3 2238.1 297.3 2262.4 337.4 2271.9 338.4 z"></path>
      <path d="M2337.9,304.9L2331.9 292.9 2331.2 285.7 2332.2 283.5 2340.2 277.8 2329.7 270.2 2327.4 265.9 2322.4 275.2 2313.4 284.9 2300.6 294.4 2301.1 300.4 2294.6 300 2292.9 300 2289.6 300.9 2295.4 323.3 2304.2 324.3 2315.7 328.7 2315.7 333 2320.9 332 2328.7 321.4 2328.7 312.7 2332.9 303.9 z"></path>
      <path d="M2355.2,323.2L2352.7 318.7 2360.4 312.9 2358.7 310.4 2351.2 315.4 2349.2 315.4 2345.4 309.9 2346.7 307.5 2352.9 304.5 2362.2 307.4 2364.9 307.3 2371.9 300.7 2369.2 297.8 2362.7 302.8 2358.4 302.8 2352.2 299.8 2347.7 299.9 2342.7 308 2339.4 322 2337.9 327.5 2341.7 332.3 2339.2 339.4 2339.2 340.7 2344.9 340.7 2346.9 322.9 2348.7 323.4 2351.9 339.5 2355.2 340.4 2358.2 333.5 z"></path>
      <path d="M2305.9,350L2291.9 346.7 2275.9 343.3 2271.4 346.4 2272.4 349.2 2287.1 352.5 2294.6 353.9 2297.9 357.3 2306.4 357.9 2310.4 361.4 2314.2 360.4 2317.4 357.4 2311.2 354.5 z"></path>
      <path d="M2320.9,359.9L2323.2 362.3 2328.4 360.3 2324.7 357.9 z"></path>
      <path d="M2336.9,358.7L2335.2 356.2 2330.9 356.4 2331.7 359.5 2335.4 360.5 z"></path>
      <path d="M2335.4,365.4L2339.7 368.9 2342.9 368.9 2340.2 364.8 z"></path>
      <path d="M2345.2,359.5L2343.2 357.9 2341.4 359.3 2340.4 361.3 2347.9 362.4 2353.9 359 2350.4 358 z"></path>
      <path d="M2365.9,360.4L2357.4 367.7 2358.2 369.5 2361.9 368.9 2366.2 364.9 2374.7 363.7 2372.9 360.8 z"></path>
      <path d="M2330.9,257.9L2341.7 246.2 2337.4 239.9 2335.9 242.7 2335.2 246 2327.2 256.4 2327.7 258.4 z"></path>
      <path d="M2356.4,238.2L2350.7 235.9 2350.4 244.4 2353.7 247.5 2354.7 253.7 2357.9 254.4 2359.4 250.5 2356.9 248.8 z"></path>
      <path d="M2364.2,246L2363.4 239.5 2359.4 239.3 2359.4 246.8 2361.2 249.7 z"></path>
      <path d="M2365.9,240.7L2368.9 240.7 2368.4 233.9 2365.2 231.9 2361.4 232.7 2364.4 236.8 z"></path>
      <path d="M2372.9,251.9L2367.4 248 2367.9 252.9 2362.4 257.5 2357.7 258 2352.7 263.4 2352.9 265.9 2357.4 264.4 2360.7 262.4 2363.4 269.4 2368.4 272.8 2370.4 272 2372.2 269.9 2368.4 266 2370.7 264.3 2373.2 266.4 2374.9 263.4 2373.2 259.9 z"></path>
      <path d="M2345.2,226.2L2347.9 224.2 2352.9 224.9 2353.9 229.4 2357.7 229.7 2359.4 227.3 2357.2 224.2 2354.4 221.5 2348.7 220.9 2345.4 215.9 2349.2 210.4 2349.4 205.8 2346.9 199.7 2340.9 198.2 2336.4 201.3 2335.9 211 2342.9 224.4 z"></path>
      <path d="M2343.2,227.4L2344.4 232 2346.9 233.5 2348.4 231.4 2345.9 227.9 z"></path>
    </g>
    <g class="oceania southern-australia" id="southern-australia">
      <title>Southern Australia</title>
      <path d="M2340.4,464.4L2340.4 506.1 2353.9 504.7 2372.2 510.2 2370.9 517.6 2373.4 524.9 2387.2 522.4 2387.9 526.1 2378.9 532.7 2381.9 535.2 2388.4 532.7 2386.7 552.9 2399.4 562.6 2401.9 561.7 2401.9 464.4 z"></path>
    </g>
    <g class="oceania papua-new-guinea" id="papua-new-guinea">
      <title>Papua New Guinea</title>
      <path d="M2383.2,310.3L2385.4 305.9 2386.7 304.4 2384.4 301.9 2381.2 300.8 2379.7 295.9 2376.4 303.7 2381.4 310.3 z"></path>
      <path d="M2392.4,322.4L2389.7 321.4 2382.7 322.9 2380.7 325 2382.4 327.9 2386.9 326.3 2389.7 324.5 2393.9 327.9 2395.7 326.4 z"></path>
      <path d="M2536.2,451.9L2544.2 462.7 2548.2 464.6 2548.9 460.2 2536.9 448.9 z"></path>
      <path d="M2492.4,327.4L2490.9 329.4 2499.2 336.7 2500.2 340.9 2502.4 340.7 2502.7 336.3 2500.2 334 z"></path>
      <path d="M2496.4,337.7L2494.9 338 2493.9 342.4 2490.7 344.4 2481.4 346 2481.9 349.5 2491.7 349 2497.9 345.2 2497.4 338.4 z"></path>
      <path d="M2509.9,344.8L2507.4 345.3 2509.7 351.2 2513.4 354.8 2514.4 353.8 2513.9 349.9 z"></path>
      <path d="M2522.7,358.7L2520.7 354.5 2517.9 353.9 2518.2 357.9 2520.4 360 z"></path>
      <path d="M2520.9,363.7L2518.9 365.8 2520.9 369.7 2523.4 370.4 2523.4 367.8 z"></path>
      <path d="M2532.4,366.7L2529.9 362.4 2525.7 361.4 2527.2 365.7 2530.7 369.7 z"></path>
      <path d="M2539.7,372.2L2534.4 367.8 2535.4 373 2537.7 376.3 z"></path>
      <path d="M2541.2,384.9L2539.9 379.9 2537.2 379.4 2536.2 380.9 2539.2 384.8 z"></path>
      <path d="M2527.7,388.4L2530.4 391.9 2532.4 390.7 2530.7 386.9 z"></path>
      <path d="M2561.2,409.4L2558.9 412.2 2559.9 415.4 2560.9 416.1 2562.9 413.6 z"></path>
      <path d="M2566.2,420.2L2564.7 417.7 2562.2 418.1 2562.2 420.4 2564.7 421.1 z"></path>
      <path d="M2564.4,440.2L2565.9 441.9 2568.7 441.1 2565.4 438.6 z"></path>
      <path d="M2608.2,434.9L2606.2 437.7 2605.9 440.9 2608.2 443.4 z"></path>
      <path d="M2471.7,354L2475.9 351.9 2472.9 345.2 2466.4 344.9 2464.9 337.7 2448.2 326.4 2445.4 326.2 2432.9 318.2 2422.9 324.9 2419.2 327.2 2413.2 323.4 2412.9 311.3 2409.9 310.9 2402.7 311.8 2398.2 315 2399.9 318.9 2407.7 320.3 2407.7 321.7 2402.9 325.7 2405.2 333.9 2407.7 334 2409.7 325.9 2413.4 325.9 2414.9 333.9 2433.4 349 2433.9 360.9 2440.2 367.8 2444.7 367.7 2444.7 367.7 2445.2 367.5 2445.4 367.5 2445.4 367.5 2450.7 367.4 2458.7 358.2 2465.2 358.4 2469.4 362.3 2470.9 373.9 2484.4 381 2487.9 379.8 2487.9 375.4 2476.9 366.4 z"></path>
    </g>
    <g class="oceania eastern-australia" id="eastern-australia">
      <title>Eastern Australia</title>
      <path d="M2396.4,589.9L2396.9 598.4 2405.9 597.9 2416.4 582.1 2399.4 577.7 z"></path>
      <path d="M2467.7,466.4L2471.2 464.1 2463.9 441.6 2456.2 436.1 2457.4 405.7 2450.2 400.2 2448.4 383.2 2444.9 383.2 2432.7 423.2 2426.2 423.9 2403.9 464.4 2403.9 562.1 2406.7 561.2 2410.4 564.7 2431.4 561.7 2451.4 529.6 2458.4 527.7 2472.9 501.1 2476.7 477.9 z"></path>
    </g>
    <g class="oceania western-australia" id="western-australia">
      <title>Western Australia</title>
      <path d="M2339.9,411.6L2340.4 418.9 2335.7 425.6 2323.4 425.6 2297.6 436.4 2288.6 460.7 2287.9 503.7 2281.4 508.7 2280.6 512.9 2289.6 519.1 2311.9 514.7 2323.4 514.7 2327.7 508.7 2338.2 506.7 2338.2 462.4 2345.5 462.4 2345.5 408.2 z"></path>
    </g>
    <g class="oceania northern-australia" id="northern-australia">
      <title>Northern Australia</title>
      <path d="M2409.9,406.7L2418.2 384.2 2402.4 381.2 2384.9 386 2380.2 400.1 2372.4 401.9 2371.9 392.2 2347.2 407.1 2347.2 462.4 2402.7 462.4 2424.9 421.9 z"></path>
    </g>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi all, MANY THANKS! You all ROCK!

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this ?

```
$('#svg-container').bind('click', function(event) {
    alert(event.target.id);
 });
```

Comment: Hi Benil, it returns a blank. So no errors, but the alert message box is empty

Comment: @TheRealPapa   http://jsfiddle.net/rLJMh/494/ .. that the fiddle .. i was getting the id

Answer (score 0):

You can use [event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) for this. Something like this should work:

**JS**

```
$( "#svg-container" ).on( "click", "g", function( event ) {
    var elementId = $(event.target).attr("id");
    alert(elementId);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Event delegation is not required here. An event handler will do the job. 
If you are using `jQuery`, this should make it work.

```
$('#svg-container').bind('click', function(event) {
    alert($(event.target).closest("g").attr("id"));
});
```